# What is the inverse Laplace transform of this?

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

Can you give me a hand with this inverse Laplace transform?

$$H(s) = \frac{s^2 + 10^{12}}{s^2 + s\cdot10^6 + 10^{12}}$$

It is the transfer function of an RLC series circuit and $Vo(s) = VL(s) + VC(s)$.

Comment: MMA says: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s^2+10^{12}}{s^2+s 10^6+10^{12}}\right](t)=\delta (t)-\frac{1000000 e^{-500000 t}
   \left(\sqrt{3} \cos \left(500000 \sqrt{3} t\right)-\sin \left(500000 \sqrt{3} t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @JuanT: We have the partial fraction expansion as $$1-\dfrac{1000000 s}{s^2+1000000 s+1000000000000}$$ Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the tip's.

I finally choose the @Moo advice.

```
H(s) = 1 - (s+0.5*10^6) / ((s+0.5*10^6)^2 + 0.75*10^12) + (0.5*10^6) / ((s+0.5*10^6)^2 + 0.75*10^12)
h(t) = δ(t) + (0.5*10^6/0.75*10^12)* exp(-0.5^6*t)*sin(sqrt(0.75*10^12)*t) - 0.5*10^6*exp(-0.5^6*t)*cos(sqrt(0.75*10^12)*t)
```

It is correct?
Thank you again.
Juan.